# Как реализовать однострочный экземпляр класса

Tags: c#, ооп

Помогите, реализовать этих 4 экземпляра класса в однострочный экземпляр класса

```
MyComplex A = new MyComplex(1, 1);
MyComplex B = new MyComplex();
MyComplex C = new MyComplex(1);
MyComplex D = new MyComplex();
```

Я знаю, что можно как-то сделать в C# так, но не понимаю как

```
MyComplex A(1,1), B, C(1), D;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно перегрузить [операторы преобразования](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).
Кортеж из двух чисел или одно число неявно конвертируем в наш класс (или структуру).

```
public class MyComplex
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public MyComplex(int x) : this(x, 0) { }

    public MyComplex(int x, int y) => (_x, _y) = (x, y);

    public static implicit operator MyComplex(int x) => new MyComplex(x);

    public static implicit operator MyComplex((int x, int y) v) => new MyComplex(v.x, v.y);

    public override string ToString() => $"{_x}, {_y}";
}
```

Тогда становится возможной следующая запись.

```
MyComplex A = (1, 1), B = (2, 2), C = 3, D = (0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(var A, var B, var C) = (new MyComplex(1, 1), new MyComplex(), new MyComplex(1));
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct

Comment: Еще короче: `var (A, B, C) = (...);`

Answer (score 2):

В C# 9.0 можно написать так, при условии, что есть подходящие конструкторы:

```cs
MyComplex A = new (1, 1), B = new (), C = new (1), D = new ();
```

Comment: Я использую C# 8.0, не знаю какой конструктор сделать, что бы можно было однострочное сделать

Comment: @Arnnold так переведите проект на .NET 5, и будет C# 9.0. Для проекта .NET Core 3.1 делов - пара кликов мышкой.